# Time complexity of a function with time 1 + 8 + 27 + 64 + ... + sqrt(n)^3?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

I have been told that

> 1 + 8 + 27 + 64 + ... + (√n)<sup>3</sup> = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 8):

To make sure I understand what you're saying, you are curious in why the sum

> 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + (√n)<sup>3</sup> = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

One way to do this would be to look up [a formula for the sum of the first m cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_%28algebra%29#Sum_of_first_n_cubes).  This is equal to

> (m(m + 1) / 2)<sup>2</sup>

So let's plug in m = √n, which gives

> 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + (√n)<sup>3</sup>
>
> = ((√n)((√n) + 1) / 2)<sup>2</sup>
>
> = ((n + √n) / 2)<sup>2</sup>
>
> = (n<sup>2</sup> + 2n√n + n) / 4

This final expression gives the exact value of the sum of the first √n perfect cubes.  Note that this expression is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), because the n<sup>2</sup> is the dominant term.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for being able to decipher what the OP is asking.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and helpful response! Much appreciated!